# Счетчик посетителей на основе Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, raspberry-pi, искусственный-интеллект

Есть задача сделать счетчик посетителей на основе Raspberry Pi 4 и камеры. Камера закреплена в таком положении, как показано на фото. Какую технологию оптимальнее всего применять для детектирования фигуры человека?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно учитывать, что ресурсы ограничены - так как используем Raspberry Pi.

Если применять нейронные сети, то посоветуйте хорошую архитектуру, пожалуйста. А также, на каком датасете её обучать. Создать свой собственный датасет можем без проблем; но что лучше детектировать - фигуру человека или, например, только голову?
Может можно применить другие методы детектирования, не нейронные сети?

Ещё стоит учитывать, что люди могут скапливаться в толпу, а точность в нашей задаче крайне важна.
Также, положение камеры, при необходимости, можно поменять.

Comment: Raspberry Pi слабоват для этого. надо брать нвидию. а лучший вариант подсчета это по головам при построении глубины на  двух камерах.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать модель "нвидии"

Comment: https://www.nvidia.com/ru-ru/autonomous-machines/embedded-systems/jetson-nano/

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: посмотри там с кодом есть https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/community/jetson-projects#detection_tracking